# Incorrect path name where build in Jenkins

Tags: go, jenkins, go-modules

I cannot build my apps on Jenkins. I try build it locally and it works. My apps using go wrapper and go mod

this is what jenkins result according to the failure:

```
./build.sh: 6: ./build.sh: [[: not found
go get .: path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_XXX_develop is not a package in module rooted at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_XXX_develop
ERROR: go get
```

I using custom build.sh like this (only from line 1-6 when the problem occurs):

```
CWD=$(cd . && pwd)
PRG=$0
BASEDIR=$(cd "$(dirname ${PRG})" && pwd)
BASENAME=$(basename ${PRG})
APPNAME=${BASENAME}
while [[ -L "$BASEDIR/$BASENAME" ]]; do
    PRG=$(readlink "$BASEDIR/$BASENAME")
    BASEDIR=$(cd "$BASEDIR" && cd "$(dirname ${PRG})" && pwd)
    BASENAME=$(basename "$PRG")
done
```

I never use $GOPATH due i using go-mod instead. I have use this build.sh and jenkinsfile easily, but after go update to 1.13.1, it seems it show problem.

Comment: update: I have check my workspace and see there's something wrong with my go.mod file. In my git repo, it exists with several list of modules are needed. But when I check my Jenkins workspace, there's only my repo name and the go version that Jenkins workspace use

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `[[` is [zsh/ksh/bash built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306141/7490), make sure your script runs with bash.

It should start with the proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/bin/bash
```